# Python requests module url encode

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send json as a parameter thru a get method for an api, I found that the url to which it is hitting is little bit different from the original url. Some ":%20" text is inserted in between the url. Not sure why this difference is coming, Can someone help

```
Original URL: http://258.198.39.215:8280/areas/0.1/get/raj/name?jsonRequest=%7B%22rajNames%22%3A%5B%22WAR%22%5D%7D

My URL : http://258.198.39.215:8280/areas/0.1/get/raj/name?jsonRequest=&%7B%22rajNames%22:%20%22WAR%22%7D
```

Python code:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token}
json = {'rajNames':'WAR'}
url = 'http://258.198.39.215:8280/areas/0.1/get/raj/name?jsonRequest='
r = requests.get(url, params=json.dumps(json),headers=headers)
print _r.url
```

Comment: Spaces are fine in JSON data and don't influence the decoding; why do you think it is a problem?

Comment: Can u compare the original & my url? they are different, i want the exact same url as original one..

Comment: Careful naming your dict 'json' - it's also the name of the module.  Shouldn't the json.dumps() fail because of that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The spaces are not the problem; your method of generating the query string *is*, as is your actual JSON payload.

Note that your original URL has a **different** JSON structure:

```
>>> from urllib import unquote
>>> unquote('%7B%22rajNames%22%3A%5B%22WAR%22%5D%7D')
'{"rajNames":["WAR"]}'
```

The `rajNames` parameter is a list, not a single string.

Next, `requests` sees all data in `params` as a *new* parameter, so it used `&` to delimit from the previous parameter. Use a dictionary and leave the `?jsonRequest=` part to `requests` to generate:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token}
json_data = {'rajNames': ['WAR']}
params = {'jsonRequest': json.dumps(json_data)}
url = 'http://258.198.39.215:8280/areas/0.1/get/raj/name'
r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print _r.url
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer <access_token>'}
>>> json_data = {'rajNames': ['WAR']}
>>> params = {'jsonRequest': json.dumps(json_data)}
>>> url = 'http://258.198.39.215:8280/areas/0.1/get/raj/name'
>>> requests.Request('GET', url, params=params, headers=headers).prepare().url
'http://258.198.39.215:8280/areas/0.1/get/raj/name?jsonRequest=%7B%22rajNames%22%3A+%5B%22WAR%22%5D%7D'
```

You can still eliminate the spaces used in the JSON output from `json.dumps()` by setting the `separators` argument to `(',', ':')`:

```
>>> json.dumps(json_data)
'{"rajNames": ["WAR"]}'
>>> json.dumps(json_data, separators=(',', ':'))
'{"rajNames":["WAR"]}'
```

but I doubt that is really needed.

Comment: I love you @Martijn Pieters